# Undoing git merge --squash

Tags: git, merge

git merge --squash is something I did to merge another feature branch into my main branch, just to realize later that I have lost some important history which was part of feature branch.

How do I get the history back from feature branch into main branch if there have been lot of commits into main branch on top of my merge commit?

If I do a merge of feature branch into my main branch again, will it solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

if you merge in the feature branch, this will probably look kind of silly, because you have similar changes in the squash merge and in the feature branch, but the history will be there.

if you changed something in the same places that have been edited in the feature branch, you will most likely have to resolve some merge conflicts though.

Comment: agree, the conflicts will have to be resolved. Is there any other way you suggest to get the history back?

Comment: you could also cherry-pick the relevant commits.

Answer (score 0):

If you do know what commits you left out of the main branch, just `cherry-pick` them, either one by one (`git cherry-pick <COMMIT-SHA>` for each one), or by using `rebase --interactive`.

Having checked out the feature branch, do `git rebase --interactive master` (assuming `master` is your main branch). Your `$EDITOR` will pop up, with the list of commits in your feature branch that are not in your main one, each preppended by a `pick` constant and it's short SHA hash. Deleting the lines of commits you know you already squashed into `master` and saving that file would make `git` cherry-pick them in batch. Of course, you would have to resolve conflicts if they arise, but having big conflicts (say, 80% of the commit has conflicts) can be a warning saying you're applying a commit you've previously merged.